# color polygons based on 2nd layer lat and long

Tags: carto

I have nyc PLUTO map as layer one (parcel map showing polygons of building outlines)
I have a second layer with Lat and Long identifying categories of buildings.

I would like my layer one polygons to be colored if they have the second layer intersecting with them

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a little bit of PostGIS:

```
SELECT 
  t1.* 
FROM 
  t1, t2
WHERE 
  ST_Intersects(t1.the_geom,t2.the_geom)
```

If your map pluto data is called `t1` and your points are in table `t2`, this query will return only the data from your map pluto table where the geometries intersect.